# logic error when trying to find the average of an array

Tags: java

i made a method that calculates the average of an array.  im getting weird numbers though.  when i constructed an array consisting of 1, 9, 5, 0, 7 it said the average was 3,  it should be 5 but i cant see whats wrong with my method.

```
public static int Average(Array_one A) {
        int ave = 0;
        int[] a = A.values;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.size; i++) {
            double tmp = a[i] * 1.0;
            ave += (tmp / A.size);
        }
        return ave;
```

Comment: declare `ave` as a `double`

Comment: `1+9+5+0+7 = 22 / 5 = 4.4`

Comment: Use a Debugger to find it out

Comment: Take care about jama naming conventions. Variable names should start with lower case character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The avg is not 5 it comes 4.4 by using following code.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

        double ave = 0;
        int[] a = {1, 9, 5, 0, 7};
        double tmp = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            tmp += a[i];
        }
        ave += (tmp / a.length);
        System.out.println(ave);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to find a `sum` first and then divide it by elements amount. To not loose a precision.

```
public static double avg(int[] arr) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int val : arr)
        sum += val;

    return (double)sum / arr.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pull the division outside of the for loop so you're adding all of the numbers in the array, then dividing by the total

```
public static int Average(Array_one A) {
    int ave = 0;
    int[] a = A.values;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size; i++) {
        double tmp = a[i] * 1.0;
        ave += tmp;
    }
    ave = ave/A.size;
    return ave;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your mathematics:

You are adding 1/6 + 9/6 + 5/6 + 0/6 + 7/6.

Which comes out to 22/6. Except that you declared ave as an int, so your progam is throwing away remainders and causing all sorts of mathematical issues.

You should declare the average as a double first.
Then, you should add up all of the numbers into tmp *without dividing*.

After that, divide tmp by ave and you should get the correct result.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use streams?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr = {1,9,5,0,7};

        double average = Arrays.stream(arr)
                .average()
                .orElse(-1);
        System.out.println(String.format("Average: %s", average));

    }
```

Comment: Maybe because op should implement the logic of average by it's own?

Comment: because im not allowed to use any method from javas API this is for school lol